# Command object bind to Domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When a domain class is used as a command object and there is an id request parameter, the framework will retrieve the instance of the domain class from the database using the id request parameter.
How can i disable this feature, i do not want the framework go to the database to retrieve the domain instance

Comment: Why do you want to disable that feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can still do databinding from request params with a slightly more verbose style; change

```
def myAction(MyDomainClass myDomainClass) {
   ...
}
```

to

```
def myAction() {
    MyDomainClass myDomainClass = new MyDomainClass(params)
   ...
}
```

This will not trigger a database call if there's an `id` in `params` and will ignore `id` and `version` properties since they're not bindable by default.